# Text is not rendered in VR mode on phone - ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, three.js, virtual-reality, webvr

So I am working on a project by using the [webvr-boilder-plate](https://github.com/borismus/webvr-boilerplate)

It is weird that the text is not rendered in VR mode on phone, but it is rendered in web browser(Firefox). I also added a cube to test, the cube is rendered in both iPhone and web browser(Firefox)

Here is code for both cube and the text:

```
// Create 3D objects.
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
// Position cube mesh
cube.position.z = -1;
scene.add(cube);

function displayCurrentStory(name) {
  scene.remove(currentStoryTextMesh);
  console.log("currentStoryText:",name);
  currentStoryText = new THREE.TextGeometry(name, {
  size: .25,
  height: .05,
  curveSegments: 12,
  font: "helvetiker"
});
currentStoryTextMesh = new THREE.Mesh(currentStoryText, 
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xFF00FF}
 ));
currentStoryTextMesh.position.y = 0.2;
currentStoryTextMesh.position.z = -1;
currentStoryTextMesh.rotation.x = 0.0;
//currentStoryTextMesh.rotation.y = -180;
scene.add(currentStoryTextMesh);}
```

Any insights?

Comment: alight....figured out I made a very stupid mistake.....I only did it for onDocumentMouseUp, I also need to add them to the "onDocumentTouchEnd(event)"...

Comment: Glad you solved it. You might want to delete this question, since it's not really helpful to anyone else, given the actual problem